# Passport-Facebook and the JavaScript Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js

I'm trying to authenticate users with Facebook using Passport-Facebook in Node.js/Express. The typical passport approach is to forward the user to /auth/facebook, which prompts the user with the typical facebook auth stuff, and then sends them to a callback url: /auth/facebook/callback.

I'd like to perform the authentication without the user having to leave the page; ie. with a popup. Using the JavaScript SDK, I can achieve this, but after they've authenticated I'd like to trigger passport to save the user's details as if they used the normal passport approach. Has anyone else accomplished this using Passport and the Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use passport-facebook-token.

Get token with JS SDK and pass it to passport route.

https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token